# Stream private data to google collab TPUs from GCS

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-datasets, google-cloud-tpu

So I'm trying to make a photo classifier with 150 classes. I'm trying to run it on google colab TPUs, I understood I need a `tfds` with `try_gcs = True` for it & for that I need to put a dataset on google colab cloud. So I converted a generator to a tfds, stored it locally using

```
my_tf_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(datafeeder.allGenerator,
                           output_signature=(
     tf.TensorSpec(shape=(64,64,3), dtype=tf.float32),
     tf.TensorSpec(shape=(150), dtype=tf.float32)))

tf.data.experimental.save(my_tf_ds,filename)
```

Then I sent it to my bucket on GCS.
But when I try to load it from my bucket with

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
dsFromGcs = tfds.load("pokemons",data_dir = "gs://dataset-7000")
```

It doesn't work and gives available datasets like :

```
- abstract_reasoning
- accentdb
- aeslc
- aflw2k3d
- ag_news_subset
- ai2_arc
- ai2_arc_with_ir
- amazon_us_reviews
- anli
- arc
```

that are not on my GCS bucket.

When loading it myself from local:

```
tfds_from_file = tf.data.experimental.load(filename, element_spec= (
     tf.TensorSpec(shape=(64,64,3), dtype=tf.float32),
     tf.TensorSpec(shape=(150), dtype=tf.float32)))
```

it works, the dataset is fine.

So I don't understand why I can't read it on gcs, can we read private ds on GCS? Or only already defined datasets. I also gave the role `Storage Legacy Bucket Reader` on my Bucket to the public.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `data_dir` argument to [tfds.load](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/load) is where the module will store things locally on your device and the `try_gcs` is whether to stream the data or not. So the `data_dir` cannot be used to point the module to your GCS bucket.

Here are some ideas you could try:

1. You could try [these steps](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset) to add your dataset to TFDS and then you should be able to load it using `tfds.load`
2. You could get a dataset in the right format using `tf.data.experimental.save` (which I think you've already done) and save it to GCS and then load it using `tf.data.experimental.load`, which you said is working for you locally. You could follow [these steps](https://pub.towardsai.net/connect-colab-to-gcs-bucket-using-gcsfuse-29f4f844d074) to install `gcsfuse` and use that to download your dataset to Colab from GCS.
3. You could try TFRecord to load your dataset. [Here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/keras-flowers-data#4) is a codelab with explanation and then [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/fast-and-lean-data-science/02_Dataset_solution.ipynb) is a Colab example that's linked in the codelab